# Get most sold products with a specified one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table order_detail with this informations

```
id_order  id_product
1         2
1         3
2         2
2         4
2         5
2         3
3         2
3         1
4         2 
4         3
4         1
4         6
```

I would like to get most sold products(the first 5 elements)  with the current product let's say product id 2

I tried this but it returns one wrong result

```
SELECT od2.product_id, count(od2.`product_id`) FROM `ps_order_detail` od1  
LEFT JOIN ps_order_detail od2 ON od1.id_order = od2.id_order where
od2.product_id != od1.product_id AND od1.product_id=2
```

The result should be

```
product_id    count(od2.`product_id`)
3             3
4             2
1             1
5             1 
6             1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is on the right track.  Mostly, you are missing a `group by`:

```
select od.product_id, count(od2.id_order) as NumTimesWith2
from ps_order_detail od left join
     ps_order_detail od2
     on od.id_order = od2.id_order and
        od2.product_id = 2 
where od.product_id <> 2
group by od.product_id
order by count(od2.id_order) desc;
```

If you want only one such product, then add a `limit 1` to the query.

Also, this assumes that products are not repeated inside orders.  If they can be, you can quickly get a better count using `count(distinct od.id_order)`).

Comment: Thnks so much very fast, but why i'm getting the product id 2 in the result?

Comment: @tarekfellah . . . I originally wrote the query as an inner join and had the `od2.id_product <> od.id_product`.  With an inner join, that would be a filter.  The `left join` however, does something else (setting columns to `NULL` instead of filtering).  I fixed the answer.

Comment: why you order by count(*) it returns non ordered results, i changed with order by  count(od2.id_order) and it seems working